# Could not resolve placeholder my_propertySource in string value file:$ - error only happens in Unix

Tags: linux, spring, shell, unix, properties

I am getting this error only when running in Unix. I mean, with same code, I can run perfectly in Windows.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'CONF_DIR' in string value "file:${CONF_DIR}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
```

…

PropertySource with file:$

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com…
@EnableBatchProcessing
@PropertySource("file:${CONF_DIR}")
public class BatchConfig {
```

…

From Windows Command Prompt, it does work perfectly:

```
C:\20160601>SET CONF_DIR=C:/20160601/config.properties
C:\20160601>java –cp my_executable_jar.jar com/my_company/main
... no error at all since propertySource("file:$... finds the value previously settup
```

From UNIX z/OS390 shell, the above error happens

```
===> CONF_DIR=/usr/certain_path/config.properties
===> echo $CONF_DIR
/usr/certain_path/config.properties
===> ./java –cp my_executable_jar.jar com/my_company/main
... now, propertySource("file:$ will not find the value previously settup although I checked and it is there (see the echo)
```

If I tried straigh inside the BatchConfig class with

```
@PropertySource("file:/usr/certain_path/config.properties")
```

it does work. So I am guessing there is some error or misunderstood from myself between java command "file:$" and how I am setting the variable in Unix.

I carefully read a lot about both approaches and, as far as I can see, both are correct. I mean either the way I am setting the shell variable and how I am accessing this. Additionally, it works in Windows.

Comment: Try `export CONF_DIR=/usr/certain_path/config.properties' instead.

Comment: Gargoyle, thanks. It fixed my issue. If you can provide it as answer I will set as correct answer. I will be thankful if you can explain what is the difference between "CONF_DIR=/usr/certain_path/config.properties" and "export CONF_DIR=/usr/certain_path/config.properties". Kindly, note that echo does show same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export CONF_DIR=/usr/certain_path/config.properties`

If you don't use the `export`, it's only set in the current environment. If you export it, then it becomes an environment variable and is inherited by sub-processes.